# Is there a design pattern to handle construction of complex objects with a [1 → 1..*] multiplicity relationship?

Tags: api-design, design-patterns

I have two classes (A and B) that are both complex to construct, with multiple properties that must be validated at construction time. I want to use the Builder pattern to construct these objects, but among the constraints on construction of these objects are:

- An instance of A must contain multiple instances of B
- Each instance of B has a child relationship to a single instance of A

In addition, I need to be able to add new instances of B to A after A has been constructed.

It seems like this must be a pretty common scenario. Is there some pattern other than Builder or to augment Builder that handles this situation?

## Option 1 - With a "placeholder" class

The best solution that I have come up with so far uses an impotent version of the Builder class, with the `Build()` method removed (I call it a Placeholder) to specify the parameters for the child class.

```
class ClassA {
    get propertyC
    ...
    get list<A> children

    restricted constructor() {}

    BBuilder AddChild() {}
}

class ClassB {
    get propertyD
    ...
    get ClassA parent

    restricted constructor(ClassA parent)
}

class ABuilder {
    get / set propertyC
    ...
    BPlaceholder AddChild() {}

    ClassA Build() {
        VALIDATE properties
        BUILD ClassA
        foreach child { BUILD child }
    }
}

class BPlaceholder {
    get / set propertyD
    ...

    restricted constructor(ABuilder parent) {}
}

class BBuilder : BPlaceholder {
    restricted constructor(ClassA parent) {}

    ClassB Build() {
        VALIDATE properties
        BUILD child
    }
}
```

Notice that, of the 5 classes in this example, the only one that can be simply constructed is `ABuilder`. The other classes are all instantiated, either directly or indirectly, through this class.

## Option 2 - Similar to Abstract Factory

Another possibility I have considered is to remove the `Build()` method from both Builder classes (in which case they are no longer Builders) and pass both classes to a third Factory class to perform the construction, similar to Abstract Factory. This doesn't seem as nice to me for two reasons, though:

- The interface doesn't intuitively guide you to the proper use
- Construction of B after A has already been instantiated is substantially different from construction of B before A has been instantiated

## Rationale for avoidance of simple construction

One possibility is to just use simple construction, something like this:

```
objA = new ClassA()
objA.Add(new ClassB(objA))
```

This is obviously a possibility, but it is missing a key element found in the Builder pattern. Builder allows you to ensure that there is no way to construct an "incomplete" instance of a class. My constraints state that a valid instance of `ClassA` **must** have **at least** one child of type `ClassB`. In the example above, `objA` exists (for a short time) without any children, and is hence invalid.

Comment: I guess design patterns are ontopic here, but huge chunks of source code are definitely now. Please use a small example (in pseudo code) to make your point. Also, make sure that your are not asking a code review question; for this site, you'd have to ask about a concept or for a reference.

Comment: @Raphael - Apologies. I'm not looking for a code review. I figured that actual code might make the question clearer. Thanks for your comment. I'm really looking for a pattern recommendation here. I can come up with several solutions, but one of the benefits of patterns is that they facilitate communication and understanding. With the solution I have come up with, it's difficult to clearly and concisely explain what I did and why. If I use a documented pattern, then the what and why already exist, and I just need to reference them. I haven't found a pattern that fits my requirements, though.

Comment: @D.W. - I have added a section to address your question. Hopefully this makes what I'm looking for a bit clearer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The answer here most likely depends a lot on how you are deciding what As and Bs to create.  If you could give more context around what data and/or events lead to the creation of these object, it would help.

Comment: Also, are these immutable objects or is there simply a minimum of 2 Bs and more can be added to A later?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you can simply create class A which contains list of objects class B. Both can have only builders (no implicit construction which adds possibility of validation). You can then make sure that A won't be constructed without at least n children of class B (your rules). After that you can use method add of class A with builder of class B.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along the lines of...

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> childern {get;private set;}
    public A(DataReader dataForA, DataReader dataForBs)
    {
        //validate and set A properties from first datareader,
        ///validate we have at least one B
        while(dataForBs.Read())
        {
            var parent = this;
            var b = new B(dataForBs, parent) //validate b data in constructor
            this.childern.Add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Using datareaders here for simplicity, but obviously you could have any 'raw' data construct or just a list of parameters.

Since all the validation, child construction and linking is done in the constructor for A or B it should be impossible to have an instance of either A with no children or B with no parent.

You will need to create your own version of List which you cant remove everything from but I guess this is outside the scope of your problem